# Email-sending class for GAE

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

Please review this:

```
class KoolDailyReminderAfterWeek(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info('sending reminders')
        timeline = datetime.now () - timedelta (days = 7)
        edge = datetime.now () - timedelta (days = 8)
        ads = Ad.all().filter("published =", True).filter("added <", timeline).filter("url IN", ['www.koolbusiness.com']).filter("added >", edge).fetch(99999)
        for ad in ads:
            logging.info('sending reminder to %s', ad.name)
            if ad.title:
                subject= ad.title
            else:
                subject = 'Reminder'
            message = mail.EmailMessage(sender='Kool Business <info@koolbusiness.com>', subject=subject)
            message.body = """
            Hello!<br>Now your ad <a href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/vi/%d.html">%s</a> has been out for a week. If you already have sold your product you can remove your ad.<br><br>Some advice to promote your ad:<br>Change + Renew the ad and it will be on top of the list. You can also change text and price.<br>Change the ad if you only want to lower the price or change the ad text<br>Renew so that the ad will be on top if the list. <br><br>Best regards,<br>Koolbusiness.com
            """  % (ad.key().id(),ad.title)
            message.html = """
            <html><head></head><body>
            Hello!<br>Now your ad <a href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/vi/%d.html">%s</a> has been out for a week. If you already have sold your product you can remove your ad.<br><br>Some advice to promote your ad:<br>Change + Renew the ad and it will be on top of the list. You can also change text and price.<br>Change the ad if you only want to lower the price or change the ad text<br>Renew so that the ad will be on top if the list. <br><br>Best regards,<br>Koolbusiness.com
            </body></html>
            """  % (ad.key().id(),ad.title)
            message.to=ad.email
            message.send()
            logging.info('sent email to: ' +ad.email)
```

YAML

```
 - description: daily mailout
   url: /report/dailyafterweek
   schedule: every 24 hours
```

[Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767524/email-framework-for-appengine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that framework, so I can only provide some general points:

- You can rewrite the `if` statement to `subject = ad.title or 'Reminder'` (see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27461/refactor-python-code-with-lots-of-none-type-checks/28002#28002)).
- You are a bit inconsistent with spacings (before and after `=`, `,`, `()`, etc.), and string formatting (your second and third `logging.info`)
- I'd recomment spreading both those chained `filters` and overly long strings over multiple lines.
- Maybe you could use some helper method to derive the HTML version of the message from the plain-text version or vice versa?